# ClickOnce Signing: How to use the same Test Certificate on 2 different computers?

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual Studio folder is synchronized with Dropbox so I work on two different computers.

The first time I open and run the Solution on the computer I get the error:

"An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\myTest.exe."

So I need to go to Signing and Create Test Certificate for this computer to continue working and running the program.

When I move to the other computer I need to make the move again and I have a lot of TemporaryKey.pfx files on the Solution Explorer that I can remove if I want.

**How can I make a Test Certificate for working on both computers? Or can I just uncheck the "Sign the ClickOnce manifiests" option?**

I read somewhere that signing is not obligatory on Net 3.5 or higher

Comment: If you would use a real source control, you could prevent the key files from checking in - but I don't know if you can tell dropbox to not synchronize the key files

Comment: I'm using the integrated GIT on Visual Studio. I will check your solution with the tip on this answer http://superuser.com/questions/469776/how-to-exclude-files-not-folders-from-dropbox-sync

Comment: @ChristianSauer another solution is uncheck the "Sign the ClickOnce manifiests" option for debugg/run and only check again just for the Publish part